# overloading indexer in typescript with string key and numeric key

Tags: typescript

I am trying to add some types to some old code.

There is a `transitionData` object, that might have objects added by index like this:

`this.transitionData[id] = transition`

where `id` is a `number` and `transition` is a `Transition` type.

Or it might be:

`transitions[t].timer.stop()`

Where `t` is a string and `timer` is of type `Timer`.

I would like this interface:

```
export interface TransitionData {
  [index: number]: Transition
  [key: string]: {timer: Timer}
}
```

but typescript complains:

> Numeric index type 'Transition' is not assignable to string index type '{ timer: Timer; }

Answer (score 1):

Create two index signatures and merge them together.

```
interface TransitionMap {
    [index: number]: Transition
}

interface TimerMap {
    [index: string]: { timer: Timer }
}

declare const transitionData: TransitionMap & TimerMap;
```

TypeScript will understand what goes where.

```
transitionData["1"] // Timer
transitionData[1]   // Transition
```

Comment: The reason TS is not happy about this is that the way indexing works in JS, `transitionData["1"] === transitionData[1]` (ex: https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYewdgzgLgBFBOBDSBLKLwBFFUQLhmQE8BeGAbwF8AoBZCNDMbXAbQCIBGdgXRjM4AGGNVCQQAGwCmAOgkgA5gAo4SVOiw5ErTjwCUMAPSGYQmEA)